# Яндекс.Ключ нигде не хранит пин-код. Это как?

Tags: авторизация, аутентификация, пароль, яндекс-ключ

Столкнулся с проблемой. У меня в аккаунте Яндекса включена двухфакторная аутентификация. Но в яндексе она какая-то особенная - не на основе смс, а на основе приложения [Яндекс.Ключ](https://yandex.ru/blog/company/91123), из которого можно, например, просто копировать одноразовые пароли и всё, даже оффлайн. Изначально в приложении задается пин-код, который надо соответсвенно вводить при каждом запуске. НО если ввести в приложении неверный пин-код, оно спокойно запускается, выдает одноразовые пароли, считывает QR-коды, но эти пароли (сгенерированные после ввода неверного пин-кода) не срабатывают, не позволяют зайти в аккаунт, с чем я и столкнулся.

[image: Ошибка входа]

Т.к. был уверен, что у меня просто глючат сервисы яндекса, стал писать подробное описание всех своих действий в техподдержку. В итоге выяснилось, что сам яндекс утверждает (в статье по первой ссылке и в ответе от службы поддержки), что **пин-код нигде не хранится:**

> Яндекс.Ключ не проверяет правильность пин-кода, потому что пин-код
>   нигде не хранится, но с паролем, сгенерированным с неверным пин-кодом,
>   авторизоваться не удастся.

Как такое возможно? Ясно, что пароли и пин-коды вообще нормальные компании не хранят в явном виде, а хранят их хэши. И при проверке сверяют сохраненный и введенный хэши. Действительно ли яндекс не хранит пин-коды ни в каком виде? Как тогда осуществляется проверка при авторизации? Такое вообще возможно?

Comment: Просто предположение. Возможно, пин-код участвует при высчитывании хэша?

Comment: @ImmRaytal в данный момент сижу разбираюсь, еще не совсем понял, но кажется там система промежуточных хэшей и паролей - от пин-кода хеш считается каждый раз заново и ... не хранится... Но как сгенерированный оффлайн временный одноразовый пароль сопоставляется уже при входе в почту на сайте...

Comment: Там может использоваться какая нибудь вариация на тему HOTP https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HOTP  Если пин-код используется например для расшифровки последнего выданного значения, то попытка сгенерить пароль выдаст совершенно иной результат. Хранить сам пин совершенно не нужно. на стороне яндкеса для проверки используется последний известный код из вашей последовательности. пин не нужен.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел статьи Яндекса об их системе работы с паролями.

1. [Как мы создавали менеджер паролей со стойкой криптографией и
   мастер-паролем...](https://yandex.ru/blog/company/91123)
2. [Двухфакторная аутентификация, которой удобно пользоваться](https://habr.com/en/company/yandex/blog/249547/) -
   конкретно о системе "Яндекс.Ключа".

**Теперь как я понял работу "Ключа"**

Вот схема из статьи и часть описания от самого яндекса:

> Мы решили пойти другим путем: пароль целиком генерируется из секрета,
>   но в смартфоне сохраняется только часть секрета, а часть вводится
>   пользователем при каждой генерации пароля. Таким образом смартфон сам
>   по себе является фактором владения, а пароль остается в голове
>   пользователя и является фактором знания.

[image: генерация пароля в яндекс.ключе]

При изначальной установке пин-кода в приложении одновременно однократно генерируются случайные данные = "хранимый секрет".
Из пары <пин + хранимый секрет> формируется "полноценный секрет". Этот "полноценный секрет" отправляется в облако яндекс и там хранится. 
При этом в телефоне хранится только "хранимый секрет", а "полноценный секрет" вычисляется заново каждый раз путем смешивания пина и хранимого секрета.

Как я понял, таким образом и становится возможным **"вообще не хранить нигде"** пин-код:

При каждом вводе пин-кода **в приложении вычисляется заново** "полноценный секрет", копия которого **уже есть в облаке**.
... Ну и дальше к ним прибавляется округленное время, усечение, что уже не зависит ни от пользователя, ни от соединения.